# Footer for empty cell with no separator

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder

In a special case I want to show an empty cell that has a footer with text.  I have set the cells height to 1 to hide the cells contents and this looks pretty good.  However there is still a separator above the footer that I am having a hard time trying to hide.

[image]

I have tried this to remove that line for the particular cell with no luck:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    // static tableviewcell defined in storyboard, just grab it and lets modify
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([indexPath section] == 0 && [indexPath row] == 0) {
        // if the cell I want to modify
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, cell.bounds.size.width);
    }

    return cell;
}
```

However that does not seem to work.

I have also seem messing with the tableViews separator property and setting it to NONE.  However when my service is on there will be rows in the table that I will show that do need to have a separator.

ideas?

Comment: Maybe disable separator property for tableview, then when you're actually filling the tableview with content add a custom separator to the cells. That would be easy as add a UIView of width cell.frame.size.width and height of 1

Answer (score 0):

Separator is not on a cell basis but from the table view.

`tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Should make the trick

Comment: That will do it for the entire table for every cell.  I mentioned that I did not want this.  When my service is enabled I will display cells in my table, when that happens I DO want the cells to have a separator.

Comment: You can add the separator when there is cells and hide it when there is only that cell ...